# Sending data to the shader(GLSL) is failing when I change a line of code in the shader that has nothing to do with those uniforms

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

working on a shader manager system using Jon Teapots tutorials. 
Currently Trying to integrate it with my code and find out why nothing is drawing.

When Uniforms cannot be found I print an error message to the console, using this code

```
GLuint ShaderProgram::getUniformLocation(std::string _name) const
{
    GLint loc = glGetUniformLocation( m_ProgramID, _name.c_str() );
    if( loc == -1 )
    {
        std::cerr << "Uniform \"" << _name.c_str() << "\" not found in program \"" <<m_ProgramName.c_str() << "\"\n";
    }
   return loc;
}
```

So, when I send the uniforms normally it doesn't show any errors, although nothing draws. 
In an attempt to see if vertices or anything were being recieved correctly by the shaders I tried avoiding using lighting calculations or anything and tried to output just a colour with full alpha.
So changed my fragment output from:

```
out_Color = vec4(finalColour, 1.0) * texture(textureUnit0, ex_TexCoord);
```

Which takes into account the texture and lighting calculations(thats what finalColour is).I changed this to:

```
out_Color = vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
```

My console now states that my light and material uniforms cannot be found? When this doesnt deal with the finding of these uniforms in the shader? so why would that affect it?

I define a material and light struct in my shader and use that to receive the uniforms to the gpu.

like:

```
struct lightStruct
{
vec4 ambient;
vec4 diffuse;
vec4 specular;
};

struct materialStruct
{
vec4 ambient;
vec4 diffuse;
vec4 specular;
float shininess;
};

uniform lightStruct light;
uniform materialStruct material;
```

I Send the data like so(after I declare material and light structs globally atm):

```
shaderManager.setLight( "Phong-Tex", light0 );
shaderManager.setMaterial( "Phong-Tex", material0 );
```

Here is the set light and set material functions, I know the setUniform functions work inside here as I use them for other variables.

```
void ShaderManager::setLight(std::string _program, const lightStruct light)
{
    auto program = m_ShaderPrograms.find(_program);

//check the program exists
if( program != m_ShaderPrograms.end( ) )
{
    program->second->setUniform4fv("light.ambient", 1, light.ambient);
    program->second->setUniform4fv("light.diffuse", 1, light.diffuse);
    program->second->setUniform4fv("light.specular", 1, light.specular);
    program->second->setUniform4fv("lightPosition", 1, light.position);
}
else{std::cerr << "Program " <<_program <<" could not be found in shader manager getProgramID" << " /n " ;}

}

void ShaderManager::setMaterial(std::string _program, const materialStruct material)
{
        auto program = m_ShaderPrograms.find(_program);

//check the program exists
if( program != m_ShaderPrograms.end( ) )
{
    program->second->setUniform4fv("material.ambient", 1, material.ambient);
    program->second->setUniform4fv("material.diffuse", 1, material.diffuse);
    program->second->setUniform4fv("material.specular", 1, material.specular);
    program->second->setUniform1f("material.shininess", material.shininess);
}
else{std::cerr << "Program " <<_program <<" could not be found in shader manager getProgramID" << " /n " ;}
}
```

As far as I am aware it should be working. If you guys need more code/info let me know. Tried to give all that I thought was relevant.

Comment: `glGetUniformLocation()` returning `-1` can mean that the uniform simply got optimized out.

Comment: If I remember, GLSL compilers throw away unused uniforms.

Comment: The compilers may have evolved recently. Still few years ago, unused uniforms really caused undefined behavior.

Comment: I am still using the uniforms though, just not outputting them anymore? could that still cause the issue you guys have described?

Comment: yes.  the optimizer will analyze for the absolute result.

Comment: I may be being pedantic here, but as I step through the code, before anything is drawn(so before the shaders are really used, I assume) I am still getting this. Should this be the case? I guess the optimizer will do it before the code is run?If so, thanks for clearing it up guys.

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behaviour. Uniforms which are not used will be optimized out of the compiled shader and invisible to `glGetUniformLocation`. This still happens if you use the variables in an intermediate calculation if the results of that calculation are not used in calculating any variables declared as `out` (or `varying` or `gl_FragColor` in compatibility mode shaders).

Comment: Thanks, that cleared up that problem, found why I wasn't getting anything drawing, was something to do with my skybox (all depths were set correctly and it was drawn first) so not Quite sure what caused it, I was implementing a new shader structure but using the old one for the skybox, not sure if this was the issue, just got to fix my lighting and then I'll be finished it!